# Is it possible to log an error to the console?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that basically has 25% chance of being false and a 75% chance of being true. Is there a way I can log an error to the console if it's `throwError` is equal to false?

```
const throwError = Math.random() > 0.25;

if (throwError === true) {
  console.log("yay!");
} else {
  logError("something went wrong!"); // I expect it to be something like this
}
```

Comment: Why not using console.log again?

Comment: You mean like `console.error("something went wrong!")`?

Comment: Oh thanks I don't know why i didn't think of that

Comment: You can choose the colours you want! If you want red, go with `console.error`. For a blue, go with `console.info`. If you fancy a yellow, use `console.warn`, like this: `console.warn("this comment is just a joke")`.

Comment: On a more serious note, people keep answering clear duplicates... this is SO 2019, not SO 2011.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [`console.error(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error) function.

Or you can even `throw new Error(yourMsgHere)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to log and error to the console.

```
console.log("Error");
```

Each browser has a console you can access and view the output of the console log.

Ctrl Shift J - this is the shortcut on windows

Take a look at this

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `console.error()` to through the error

You can also use the `console.exception()` to through exception .

For more detail , Visit this **[LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error)**